# Show that there exists an element $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ which remains fixed by each element of $H.$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $H$ be subgroup of $S_4$ of order $6.$ Then show that there exists an element $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ which remains fixed by each element of $H.$

Since $3|O(H)~\exists~\sigma\in H$ such that $O(\sigma)=3$ i.e. $\sigma$ is a $3$-cycle. Let $\sigma=(a\ \ b\ \ c).$ We shall show that $d\in\{1,2,3,4\}-\{a,b,c\}$ is the required fixed element. We note, due to the third Sylow theorem, that $\sigma,\sigma^2$ are the only $3$-cycles in $H.$

If possible let $\exists$ some element in $H$ which alters $d.$ Due to the Lagrange's theorem it must be an element of order $2$ that is either a transposition or the product of two disjoint transpositions.

The former case is not possible since any such $2$-cycle must contain $d$ and hence when multiplied by a $3$-cycle which excludes $d$ results a $4$-cycle, a contradiction.

Even for the later case we may arrive at a contradiction by noting that if such a element be denoted by $\tau_1\tau_2$ where $\tau_1$ includes $d$ then $\sigma\tau_1$ is a $4$-cycle (as for the above case) and so when multiplied by $\tau_2$ leaves a $3$-cycle which is distinct from both of $\sigma,\sigma^2,$ another contradiction.

Hence the result follows.

**Please tell me if it is correct.**

Comment: Note that $(1\,2\,3)\circ (1\,2)(3\,4)=(1\,3\,4)$ is not a 4-cycle

Comment: Another way to show that all elements of $H$ must fix $d$ is that, if not, then $\{a,b,c,d\}$ would be an orbit of $H$, which would have size $4$, which implies that $4$ divides $|H|$, contradiction.